# Fazer um grupo de linhas permanecerem compactadas ao abrir e fechar o Sublime

Tags: sublime-text-2

Estou com um pequeno probleminha no Sublime Text 2, ele tem uma opção na lateral esquerda na qual eu posso compactar toda uma DIV em apenas 2 linhas

[image: Seta na esquerda recolhe todo conteúdo da DIV]

Facilitando quando se tem muitas linhas, o problema que quando eu fecho o programa e abro novamente ele não volta com essa configuração, ele volta com todas as DIVs abertas.

Existe alguma configuração que eu possa fazer para que quando eu fechar o programa e voltar , ele volte com as DIVs compactadas igual eu deixei ao fechar ?

Aproveitando o tópico, toda vez que eu abro o programa ele já vem marcada a opção de Word Wrap, existe alguma maneira de configurar para toda vez que eu abrir o programa ele abra com algumas opções ja editadas , tipo um Preset de configurações ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Pedro Reis já respondeu que o `Sublime Text 2` não armazena as porções de texto compactadas (isso se chama *folding*) entre sessões e que isso pode ser feito utilizando plugins. Particularmente eu não gosto de gravar a sessão de uso e simplesmente desabilito esse recurso. Então, note que *eu não uso* os plugins que vou sugerir, ok? Eu conheço eles "de nome" (estavam aqui nos meus bookmarks, pra quem sabe um dia usar em alguma necessidade...). Se você conseguir usar com sucesso, avise aqui (em comentário ou em sua própria resposta) pra referência futura. :)

O primeiro plugin é chamado [`RegReplace`](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace). Trata-se de uma ferramenta de criação de regras de *matching* de texto (isto é, faz uma "busca" e executa uma "ação" no texto encontrado). Com essa ferramenta talvez você possa, por exemplo, criar uma busca pelo conteúdo entre as cláusulas `<div>` e `<\div>` e utilizar uma *override action* (veja como no Readme do projeto) do tipo `fold` para compactar o bloco de texto encontrado. Os plugins são inicializados alguns segundos depois do editor, então pode ser que seja fácil de executar a sua regra automaticamente no início (honestamente, eu não tenho certeza).

Este outro, chamado [`BufferScroll`](https://github.com/SublimeText/BufferScroll), parece mais apropriado para o que você quer e mais simples de usar, porque grava diferentes configurações de uso, como a posição de rolagem do texto, as marcações (*bookmarks*) e também as compactações (*foldings*).

Comment: Luiz, eu testei e funcionou tudo corretamente aqui com Buffrer Scroll, posso fechar o programa e voltar que ele armazena essas informações menores sem problema nenhum, obrigado.

Comment: @JeanBragantin Por nada! :)

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente na versão padrão o Sublime Text 2 não registra isso, até mesmo porque ocuparia mais espaço na memoria. Apesar disso existem plugins como o autocomplete que podem auxiliar. Mas desconheço um que armazene isso.

Como você está trabalhando com um projeto talvez seja interessante utilizar alguma outra IDE. O Netbeans é uma boa opção apesar de ser um pouco pesado.

Espero ter ajudado.